# ServiceStack's JSON deserializer parses invalid JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization, servicestack, servicestack-text

Given the invalid JSON text, `{ "foo" = "bar" }`, the JSON deserializer built into ServiceStack will successfully decode this into the following DTO:

```
public class FooDto {
   public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Now, perhaps that's acceptable for some use cases because it looks kind of like a C# initializer, so maybe not actually parsing JSON is a feature for this library.

However, when given the invalid JSON text, `{ "foo" xxx "bar" }`, no error is thrown and horrifyingly the Foo property is set to "xxx".

Is there a way to either (a) configure ServiceStack.Text to parse only JSON (instead of whatever non-standard variant it accepts by default) or (b) replace the serializer with, say, JSON.NET at the application level?

EDIT: It also looks like ServiceStack's deserialization behavior for its web routing code behaves differently from the behavior of `ServiceState.Text.JsonSerializer` which appears to return `default(T)` on an invalid parse.

EDIT 2 (Progress?):

```
appHost.SetConfig(new HostConfig { UseBclJsonSerializers = true });
```

Setting this option will cause ServiceStack to return a 400 Bad Request on malformed JSON, but unfortunately fails to deserialize the JSON into the given DTO.  Maybe this is part of a solution?

**SOLUTION:**

Replacing ServiceStack's default JSON serializer with a custom "application/json" handler which in turn wrapped the JSON.NET serializer ended up solving the problem.  I've included a copy of the solution code [in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22599533/641629) below.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom JSON serializer wrapping the excellent JSON.NET library.  This solution raises exceptions on invalid JSON and so returns 400 Bad Request as expected.

Caveat: This implementation ignores the Accept-Charset header as well as the charset parameter of the Content-Type header, and instead assumes UTF8.  If you're not able to assume UTF8 on the wire, you'll want to tweak this code.

```
public class UseJsonDotNet : IPlugin
{
    public JsonSerializerSettings Settings { get; set; }

    public void Register(IAppHost appHost)
    {
        appHost.ContentTypes.Register(
            "application/json",
            WriteObjectToStream,
            ReadObjectFromStream);
    }

    public void WriteObjectToStream(
        IRequest request, object response, Stream target)
    {
        var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.None, Settings);
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(target, Encoding.UTF8, 1024, true))
        {
            writer.Write(s);
        }
    }

    public object ReadObjectFromStream(Type type, Stream source)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(source, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            var s = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s, type, Settings);
            return o;
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, just register it:

```
Plugins.Add(new UseJsonDotNet { Settings = ... } );
```

Comment: ... in two days apparently.

Comment: Yep looks good, tho rather than inventing a new `RegisterNew` convention it's better to follow ServiceStack's simple [IPlugin API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Plugins#plugin-api), that way it can be registered like every other plugin, e.g using `Plugins.Add(new JsonDotNetSerializer());`

Comment: Good advice; please feel free to rewrite this as a plugin. Consider the code CC0.

Comment: Yeah, that does look better.  Is there a way to control the response from inside a plugin?  Currently, when I use this plugin and pass an invalid JSON text, ServiceStack emits a 400 Bad Request (great!), but includes an unhelpful content body along the lines of "BindingException thrown, cannot bind blah to blah".  Is there a way to control that message within the IPlugin API (e.g. to say which properties cannot be bound)?

Comment: @davidzarlengo yeah by registering an `IAppHost.UncaughtExceptionHandlers` see the [Error Handling wiki docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling#customized-error-handling)

Answer (score 3):

The wiki docs mention how to [register your own custom media types](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#custom-media-types), which will take precedence over ServiceStack's built-in formats.

You can register for ServiceStack to use a different serializer in your AppHost with:

```
this.ContentTypes.Register(MimeTypes.Json, 
    serialize: (IRequest req, object response, Stream stream) => ..., 
    deserialize: (Type type, Stream stream) => ...);
```

Comment: @davidzarlengo Now you're getting the answers from the official ServiceStack's **mythz**. I cannot compete with that ;). Is this the custom content solution that you were asking me for?

Comment: @mythz: Thanks again; I wrote a custom serializer that uses JSON.NET and it solved my issue.  Thanks for the extensibility point.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `JsConfig` class. It has some useful configuration stuff, but I'm not sure you will find what you want. There is `JsConfig.ThrowOnDeserializationError` that you can set to `true` (I don't know if the default value is `false`) and see how it will behave.

Comment: Tried it, that doesn't seem to do anything.  Also, it looks like `IAppHost.ContentTypeFilters` has been removed, so writing my own "application/json" implementation seems to not be possible.

Comment: It's not too hard to write your own implementation, and who knows, it may become more popular that ServiceStack. Just remember to let us know about it ;).

Comment: I'm not a glutton for punishment, but if I can figure out how to create a custom content type that wraps an existing JSON parser like JSON.NET then that would be a solution for me.  Your comment seems to imply that you know how to configure a custom content type for SS 4.0.4. Can you clue me in?

Comment: I did not entirely understand your **Edit 2**. What did you mean by "*but unfortunately fails to deserialize the JSON into the given DTO*"? Does that mean it now fails to desterilize valid JSON?

Comment: Yeah, that's right.  I'd send it bad JSON and it would blow up as expected, but when I sent it good JSON it would come through looking like `default(T)`.